# Прирывестое взаимодействия персонажа с CharacterController с RigidBody| Unity

Tags: unity3d, procedural-generation

У меня есть некий плот имеющий компонент RigidBody, он движется плавно и без рывков. Но игрок с CharacterController движется рывками как это видно на этой гифке https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3j7A.jpg

Переделовать движение персонажа с CharacterController на RigidBody нельзя. (У RigidBody Collision Detection стоит на Continuous Dynamic, но изменяя это - ничего не меняется)

Управление персонажа очень простое.

Answer (score 0):

Причём тут Continuous Dynamic?

> Переделовать движение персонажа с CharacterController на RigidBody
>   нельзя.

Нельзя одеть штаны через голову, хотя у некоторых всё-же получается. А переделать управление вполне можно. `CharacterController` это не инструмент, а костыли.

> Управление персонажа очень простое.

Что это значит? Какие цели? `CharacterController` или что-бы твой персонаж понимал колыхания поверхности плота? Одно с другим явно не сочетается.

И нужно ли это колыхание вообще. Если плот ещё и движется придётся делать персонажа дочерним объектам плота и следить за его наклоном, корректируя.